# Or tools cp-solver parameter linearization_level

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

tools and im using it with python to solve an optimization problem but while using the cpSolver from the cp_model i came across a certain parameter which is the linearization_level which is set in the documentation to 0 in a certain example but didn't explain it.

[image]

Can anyone explain to me what is gonna happen if i tweak the value of this parameters and thanks in advance.

Comment: See: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/sat_parameters.proto#L596